# How to make two classes for one image: .small-image { max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px; } also have the text aligned in middle using css and html

Tags: html, css, class

Think it's possible to use two different classes for a series of thumbnail images but obviously I must be doing something wrong. Could someone please suggest how I could do so.

CSS Example:

```
.small-image { max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px; } 
.textmiddle {vertical-align:middle;}
```

Only seem to be able to put code in the html for one or the other but not both. Thank you

Comment: What do you wanna achieve?

Comment: Do the thumbnail images have both classes?

Comment: I had a table with thumbnail images and names underneath that I had wanted the text centered. In css I had put
 td img {
        display: block;     Had also ended up putting .textmiddle {vertical-align:middle;}  for the content  
        margin: 0 auto; 
}

.small-image {
max-width: 100px;
max-height: 100px;
}      
 That did accomplish what I wanted but had thought there should have been a way of putting it all in one. I see someone else commented on how to do it.  Thank all of you very much, really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

try in your html element :

```
class="small-image textmiddle"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<div class="small-image textmiddle> </div>
```